# How to reload UBUNTU11.04 again which is hidden in the hard disk

Tags: 11.04

I had installed Ubuntu 11.04 as another OS ( not inside Windows). means every time i used to get a Ubuntu screen and i can select Ubuntu or windows. but once i formatted my windows. after that the 38 gb memory which was used under Ubuntu is missing means the ubuntu is there and as it is EXT type windows is not able to access that. and i am not able to boot into it.I need ubuntu i can install new version but my memory is being wasted i do not kno what to do. pl reply me asap.

Answer (score 2):

Use a live ubuntu disk or usb to boot into live mode and then use this tool

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
```

For doing it the command-line way, This link should help.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
```